# Why is `opsz` doubled to `px` on Chromium and not on Webkit?

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, variable-fonts

Variable fonts are supposed to have optical sizing proportionate to its `px` value automatically.

But it's not consistent in different browsers.

- if `font-size: 16px`

  - [in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRXv5.png) and Firefox – `opsz: 16`
  - [in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plCUq.png) – `opsz: 32`

So I have to

```css
body {
  font-variation-settings: "opsz" 16;
}
```

which is not automatic anymore, I have to redeclare every time I change `font-size`.
Is it just me? Where should I start if I want to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1305237 - there's been an issue with opsz depending on display resolution or zoom level. Aiming to release fix in Chrome 105 stable or already fixed in an up-to-date Chrome Canary.

Comment: It says I have no permission but thanks!